# How can I make Bootstrap icons work on dark background?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-sprites, bootswatch

I'm using the [Bootswatch Cyborg theme](http://bootswatch.com/cyborg/) of Twitter's [Bootstrap library](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html). However, the Cyborg theme has a dark background and light foreground colors, a negative look from the Bootstrap defaults. The icon set PNG assumes a light background, and doesn't show in the Cyborg theme. Is there a corresponding icon set for dark backgrounds? I couldn't find one on [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/)' site. Is there an easy trick to turn the icons into the negative color?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add icon-white class to your bootstrap icon and it will be white on dark.

like:

```
<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
```

This works for Bootstrap 2 as seen in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html

Comment: Wow, I had totally overlooked that. Thanks for pointing this out! Looks like Bootstrap ships with a white-based icon gallery as well.

Comment: Is there a standard way to do the same for the class="close" icon?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the .close in modals and still talking about boostrap 2: The x in .close is a font symbol and not a icon. You can set its color by applying a simple color: css rule.